# It is possible to generate console highlighting for markdown with pandoc?

Tags: markdown, highlight, pandoc

I'm writing some documentation in markdown and trying to render it with pandoc.  I'd like to be able to highlight an interactive shell session, by bolding commands typed by the user.

So, I hope that

````
```console
$ user text
program output
``` #
````

would be highlighted like

```
$ user text
program output
```

with `user text` in bold.

Is it possible to do this in pandoc?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a built-in syntax definition for bash console. But from http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#syntax-highlighting:

> If you are not satisfied with the built-in highlighting, or you
>   want highlight a language that isn't supported, you can use the
>   `--syntax-definition` option to load a [KDE-style XML syntax definition
>   file](https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/applications/katepart/highlight.html).
>   Before writing your own, have a look at KDE's [repository of syntax
>   definitions](https://github.com/KDE/syntax-highlighting/tree/master/data/syntax).

Answer (score 1):

It took me a little while to work out the syntax, but here's some simple XML to make lines starting with `$` bold:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE language SYSTEM "language.dtd">
<language name="Shell" version="1" kateversion="2.4" section="Other" extensions="*.shell" mimetype="" author="Tim Hutt (tdhutt@gmail.com)" license="MIT">
  <highlighting>
    <contexts>
      <context attribute="Output" name="Output" lineEndContext="#stay" >
        <DetectChar char="$" attribute="Command" context="Command" firstNonSpace="true"/>
      </context>
      <context attribute="Command" name="Command" lineEndContext="#pop" />
    </contexts>
    <itemDatas>
      <itemData name="Output" defStyleNum="dsNormal"/>
      <itemData name="Command" defStyleNum="dsOthers" bold="true"/>
    </itemDatas>
  </highlighting>
</language>
```

(Use ```shell instead of ```bash)

Unfortunately `bold="true"` does not work with Pandoc. I assume it just reads the resulting `defStyleNum` and feeds that into its highlighter, ignoring the other attributes.

We can abuse one of the other styles (I've used `dsOthers` here - pick one that isn't used elsewhere in your documents). Just use Pandoc's `--css=foo.css` option with some CSS like this:

Here's how it looks, with some Rust code above:

[image: demo]

It's a small improvement. I wish there was a way to copy text with ANSI colour codes from the console and have Pandoc render that but I'll settle for this.